# "Include" lambda in generic repository

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6

I follow repository pattern and I have the following method in my generic repository class:

```
    public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }
```

I would like to add the a lambda expression for including navigation properties. Is it possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, you may want to clarify what you're asking, also don't use keywords as variable names (typically that variable would get named Predicate, not "where")

Comment: @Default I know it's basic EF, i still find the question of what he wanted to do vs what he had done was confusing. It's not "including a lambda" unlike what the title says if it's what he meant, it's also not clear if the code is a sample of what he wants or what he has and need to convert etc, i maintain what i say, the question is unclear and can be interpreted in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Include(this IQueryable<T> qry, params string[] includes)
{
    foreach(var inc in includes)
         qry = qry.Include(inc);
    return qry;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var list = context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == 1).Include("Items", "Person").Single();
```

Comment: don't you need to do `qry = qry.Include(inc);`?

Comment: i'm not positive if you need to, but doing so should work. updated.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure either, that's why there is a question mark at the end :) On another note: `Single` which you are using is very different than `FirstOrDefault` which the OP is using.

Comment: This was going to be my approach too. Is there a way to strongly type the includes instead of passing strings?

Comment: there are ways to get the name of a property from a lambda. do some googling on that and you should find a way to update this to accept  a lambda instead.

Comment: @Dleh exposing with a lambda would allow manipulations on the query which might have unwanted results. e.g Append is exposed...

Answer (score 0):

There's my generic repo Get method:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> Query = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            Query = Query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
        {
            foreach (string IncludeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                Query = Query.Include(IncludeProperty);
            }
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(Query);
        }
        return Query;
    }
```